# Pry in jruby not able to paginate

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jruby, pry

I'm using pry-rails with jRuby 1.7.5(1.9.3p392) with rails 3.2.9. Whenever I'm in pry and it outputs more than one page(e.g.: when I do `help`) and has to put a page-break I will be stuck, the end of the screen looks like this:

```
<page break> --- Press enter to continue ( q<enter> to break ) --- <page break>
^M^M^M^M^M^M^M^M^C^C[2013-10-31 21:46:20] ERROR Interrupt: Interrupt
    /Users/macbook/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/pry-0.9.12.2-java/lib/pry/pry_class.rb:103:in `load_traps'
^C^C^C[2013-10-31 21:46:22] ERROR Interrupt: Interrupt
    /Users/macbook/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/pry-0.9.12.2-java/lib/pry/pry_class.rb:103:in `load_traps'
```

I won't be able to get out from pry with `q` or any other keys. When I do `ctrl-c`, it will print more `ERROR Interrupt`. The only way out is force closing the tab or `ctrl-Z`, which is even uglier. Is this a bug or am I doing it wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Looks like this is a known bug: https://github.com/pry/pry/issues/992

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work around this by turning off paging.

```
Pry.pager = nil
```