# Turn off page breaks in fly.io ssh / console output?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fly

When ssh'ing into an app (e.g. a rails app, with `fly ssh console -C "/app/bin/rails console"`), how can I prevent:

```
<page break> --- Press enter to continue ( q<enter> to break ) --- <page break>
```

and just dump everything to the console (without the breaks)?

Note I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20711826/5783745) but it didn't seem to affect it.